# NSCollectionViewGridLayout in a single row with resizable collection items which maintain an aspect ratio?

Tags: objective-c, aspect-ratio, nscollectionview

I have a NSCollectionView which uses a NSCollectionViewGridLayout to create a single row of collection view items. The row can have one or more items and can scroll horizontally is needed, i.e. one row, unlimited columns (one item per column).

The collection view items have a minimum size of 240x160 and have an aspect ration constraint of 3:2 (the width is 1.5 times the height). There is no maximum size.

All the spacing/insets are set to zero so that the items are next to each other horizontally, starting at the left-hand side of the collection view (though ideally I'd like to center the items horizontally if the total width of the items is less than the width of the collection view.)

The collection view is in the top half of a split view. When dragging the divider up/down (vertically), I'd like to resize the collection view items while maintaining the aspect ratio. The problem is that the aspect ratio constraint conflicts with the leading/trailing constraints and causes a constraint exception.

1) I've tried removing the leading/trailing constraints from the collection item view, but then the items are not flush together. I can't have gaps between the items and I can't the items overlapping each other.
2) I've tried removing the aspect ratio and the items resize correctly but don't maintain their aspect ratio.
3) I've also tried setting an aspect ratio on the collection view width such that it equals the height of the collection times the number of items times the aspect ratio, but wasn't able to get it to work correctly (and it seems kind of hack-ish). I also tried a custom layout object but I ran into different errors.
3) I was considering, but didn't try, de-activtating the aspect ratio constraint when the drag starts, and re-acivating the constraint when the drag ends but wasn't sure if this would work (it seems kind of hack-ish).

```
// setting up the grid layout
NSCollectionViewGridLayout* layout = [[[NSCollectionViewGridLayout alloc] init] autorelease];
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0;
layout.margins = NSEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
layout.maximumNumberOfRows = 1;
layout.maximumNumberOfColumns = 0;
layout.minimumItemSize = NSMakeSize(260.0, 160.0);
layout.maximumItemSize = NSZeroSize;
self.theCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
```

(not shown are the constraints in the collection view item xib file)

The desired result is to have:
a) User resizing a single row of collection view items by dragging a split view divider, and they maintain their aspect ratio while being resized.
b) Ideally, collection view items would be centered horizontally in collection view if the items don't scroll horizontally.